# Wtih .Net 5.0 what Class Library Type is the new standard?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class-library, .net-5

In the past I would use .Net Standard for my .Net Class Library type as it seemed the most universal.  However, with the introduction of .Net 5.0, .Net Standard Class Libraries are raising the yellow flag in my solution explorer.  Is there a new class library type that was introduced with .Net 5.0?

Comment: The "yellow flags" you're seeing are about something completely different. You can use .NET Standard 2.x or .NET 5 for your class libraries, as you prefer and/or as per your requirements. There's no new project type in .NET 5.

Comment: .NET is a merge of all previous environments. From [What's new in .NET 5](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/dotnet-five) : *We skipped version numbers 4.x to avoid confusion with .NET Framework 4.x. We dropped "Core" from the name to emphasize that this is the main implementation of .NET going forward. .NET 5.0 supports more types of apps and more platforms than .NET Core or .NET Framework. .NET 5.0 doesn't replace .NET Framework. .NET 5.0 doesn't replace .NET Standard.* Also: [.NET 5 and .NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-5-and-net-standard)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Notice that what you're referring to is the target framework, *not* the type of project, which hasn't changed since .NET Standard 1.0.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if there is an official Microsoft announcement or not, but I agree with Immo that [.NET 5 replaces .NET standard](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/)